# Where's my old Ask Ubuntu Account?

Tags: support, login

Ask Ubuntu seems to support Login via Facebook, Google, etc.

Some months ago it was only possible to login with an Ask Ubuntu-Account. How can I access this?

Comment: ... Uhm ... I think you're mistaken here. There was never an "Ask Ubuntu Account" login. There is [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com), which Ask Ubuntu belongs to, that's the closest equivalent to an "Ask Ubuntu Account login" there is.

Comment: I checked for accounts with the same email address and only found the one you're currently logged in with.

Comment: Oh, you are right. i was very confused, because i didn't find the log-in-button (just log in via fb, google, etc). Is it possible to merge this account with another one from stackexchange?

Comment: @jenald It is http://askubuntu.com/help/merging-accounts